# Compiz Eventually Gets Choppy and Slow

Tags: 11.04, compiz

When I do a fresh start of my machine, compiz is fast and smooth. After a few hours, it gets very choppy. For example, moving windows around just make them appear in the new place, same with switching virtual workspaces.

I am using gnome classic, `compiz --replace` doesn't seem to fix the issue. I don't think it is a resources issue because:

1. Don't see any active swapping place and 15GBytes free of ram (24 in total)
2. Radeon HD 6900 Series with 2GBytes if Video memory.
3. CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         950  @ 3.07GHz

In compiz settings vsync is not enabled. Any ideas?

Comment: I get the same on Nvidia. i7, 24GB RAM, GTX580 w/1.5GB VRAM and after 24 hours, dragging becomes a slideshow. I find that logging out and in again helps but things slow down after another chunk of time.

Comment: Possible over-heating issues causing the system to appear sluggish? Try logging into Ubuntu 2D or Gnome Classic (if you have it installed), then see if the system runs better. Maybe try a system monitor for possible clues.

Comment: The description given by Oli suggests memory leaks, I'd say.

Comment: @Misery: Know of any tool to monitor graphic card memory usage?

Comment: Interesting, I closed out a couple windows (rstudio and a chrome window with a few tabs) and it is better all of the sudden. It was sluggish when they were on other virtual desktops (not minimized). Will experiment with opening them up and minimizing etc...

Comment: If I play a video I get the same sort of behavior. If I close that video, the behavior seems to linger for about a 40-60 seconds and it then goes away.

Comment: Kyle Brandt: Not really. But for example for ASUS nVidia You can get VGA smart doctor with free CUDA dev drivers. You should check Your VGA producers website for such a tool. Some kind of VGA profiler or something similar.

Comment: I have been using ppa:vanvugt/compiz and ppa:vanvugt/unity for a day or so now and no issues since upgrading both compiz and unity from those two ppa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the newer unity and compiz from the following PPAs:

```
ppa:vanvugt/compiz
ppa:vanvugt/unity
```

This seems to have resolved the issues I am having.